# getting __SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED error from React 17 application after build

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React Chat Widget that I'm trying to integrate into a Web page. In order to make the integration, I created the build of the application using webpack ( my webpack generates a CSS file and a JS file ). I tried to integrate these files into an index.html blank page using the script tag for the JS file and the link tag for the CSS. I was expecting to get the app into the browser but there was some error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED')`. This variable was existant in the JS build file. I've tried to read about it, it looked like it was there for security. Yet, the build doesn't even recognize it, it looks like.
Here is my `webpack.config.prod.js` :

```
'use strict'
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/lib'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    library: 'react-chat-widget',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    clean: true
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js','scss'],
    alias: {
      react: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/react'),
      'react-dom': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/react-dom'),
      'react/jsx-runtime': require.resolve('./node_modules/react/jsx-runtime')
    }
  },
  target: 'web',
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /dev/],
        use: ['babel-loader', 'ts-loader']
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: ['postcss-preset-env']
              }
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              implementation: require('node-sass'),
              sassOptions: {
                includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss/')]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/,
        type: 'asset/inline'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    /**
     * Known issue for the CSS Extract Plugin in Ubuntu 16.04: You'll need to install
     * the following package: sudo apt-get install libpng16-dev
     */
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'styles.css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css'
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'react': 'React'
    })
  ],
  externals: {
    react: {
      root: 'React',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      commonjs: 'react',
      amd: 'react'
    },
    'react-dom': {
        root: 'ReactDOM',
        commonjs2: 'react-dom',
        commonjs: 'react-dom',
        amd: 'react-dom'
    }
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true
      }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
  }
};
```

Here is the `package.json`:

```
 {
  "name": "react-chat-widget",
  "version": "3.1.4",
  "description": "Chat web widget for React apps",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:Wolox/react-chat-widget.git",
  "author": "Martín Callegari <martin.callegari@wolox.com.ar>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "types": "./lib/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.prod.js",
    "test": "jest --coverage"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "chat",
    "widget",
    "javascript"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "date-fns": "^2.11.1",
    "emoji-mart": "^3.0.1",
    "firebase": "^10.1.0",
    "markdown-it": "^8.4.1",
    "markdown-it-link-attributes": "^2.1.0",
    "markdown-it-sanitizer": "^0.4.3",
    "markdown-it-sup": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.14.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.8.3",
    "@toycode/markdown-it-class": "^1.2.3",
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.10",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.5",
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.4",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.22.0",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^8.2.0",
    "babel-jest": "^19.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001219",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.4",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-wolox": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.30.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "husky": "^4.2.3",
    "jest": "^25.5.4",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.5.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "postcss": "^8.2.13",
    "postcss-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "prettier": "^1.1.0",
    "prettier-eslint": "^9.0.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^25.3.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.7",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.36.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "testURL": "http://localhost/",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/mocks/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/mocks/styleMock.js"
    }
  }
}
```

`index.html` used to test :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
    scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
<script src="./index.js">

</script>
```

I can't share the minified files since they contain so much information and it could be really hard to read.
The app code is found on https://github.com/Wolox/react-chat-widget